# Loop through all user tables and insert row in each

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

for some reason I just can not figure this out.  I have a seperate schema in PostgreSQL for notification related tables for each user connected to the server.  My plan is to have each user create a TEMP table to receive extra notification info from since Xojo doesn't support PostgreSQL payloads.
I feel like I'm starting to get close so I'll just post my code that is in my trigger function.

```
    DECLARE
        my_table    RECORD;
    BEGIN       
        FOR my_table IN 
            SELECT table_name
            FROM   information_schema.tables
            WHERE  table_schema = 'information_schema'
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO my_table.table_name (effected_row_id)
                VALUES (NEW.effected_row_id);
        END LOOP;
    END;
```

Tell me if I'm wrong, but I believe my main problem is figuring out how to use the table name returned from the SELECT statement in the INSERT statement.

EDIT:
This is my current trigger function

```
-- Function: notification.my_insert_trigger_function()

-- DROP FUNCTION notification.my_insert_trigger_function();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notification.my_insert_trigger_function()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$DECLARE
    my_table    RECORD;
BEGIN       
    FOR my_table IN 
        SELECT table_name
        FROM   information_schema.tables
        WHERE  table_schema = 'notification' AND table_name <> 'notification_global' AND table_name <> 'switcher'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE(FORMAT($f$
        INSERT INTO %s (effected_row_username)
            VALUES (%s);
        $f$, 'notification.' || my_table.table_name, NEW.effected_row_username));
    END LOOP;
RETURN new;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION notification.my_insert_trigger_function()
  OWNER TO serveradmin;
```

Comment: Can you show the DDL for this table?

Comment: I would love to. Can you explain to me how to do that?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to get a DDL.  Which table did you want it for? The table that will use this function in a trigger or the one of the tables that this function will effect?
I'll add the latter to my original post

Comment: Not an answer, but having any structure in the database repeated like this smells like a missing normalization to me, and I would recommend you reconsider your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [dynamic commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in your trigger function.
The funcion [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) is often very helpful.

```
DECLARE
    my_table    RECORD;
BEGIN       
    FOR my_table IN 
        SELECT table_name
        FROM   information_schema.tables
        WHERE  table_schema = 'information_schema'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE(FORMAT($f$
        INSERT INTO %s (effected_row_id)
            VALUES (%s);
        $f$, my_table.tablename, NEW.effected_row_id));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you klin I am so close to making this work but I still have one issue.
I used your trigger function and made some changes to fit exactly what I need.  My problem is that I keep getting an error saying that column "serveradmin"does not exist. It's getting "serveradmin" from the variable 'New.effected_row_username.  What I'm tring to figure out is out to pass the text from 'New.effected_row_username into the effected_row_username field. I'll post my modified code in my original post.

Comment: Now the function tries to insert `VALUES(serveradmin)` but it should insert `VALUES('serveradmin')`. So you have to add apostrophes: `VALUES('%s')`.